# How can I secure Google Apps Script code to be invisible from users?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google App Script application written in a Google Apps Script library.  Is there a way that I can deploy that library in such a way that my users can't see the code?

I have been looking at options such as deploying as an executable or as a web app, but I am not sure how this will work with the Google Sheets that are calling the library.

Comment: Deploy as an addon